# How to change a notary config?

Tags: corda

There are any example about starting the distributed notary based on `node.conf` or in deployNodes? It may be seen that?

```
node {
    name "O=Notary Pool,L=Sao Paolo,C=BR"
    notary = [validating : false, raft:[nodeAddress:"localhost:10020", clusterAddresses:["localhost:10023","localhost:10026","localhost:10029"]]]
    p2pPort 10002
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10003")
        adminAddress("localhost:10043")
    }
    webPort 10004
    cordapps = ["net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    extraConfig = [
            jvmArgs : [ "-Xmx1g"]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples of defining and running a distributed notary service can be found in the [notary-demo sample](https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/notary-demo).

Note that as of Corda 3.1, the API for defining distributed notary services using `CordaformDefinition` is not finalised and should be treated as experimental.